# Different pricing of apps regarding regions in country

Tags: ios, ios-appstore, app-store-connect, in-app-purchase

My customer asked me the following question:

"Imagine the situation you have an app that costs 0.99$. Is there any way to make this app free in certain area, such as chosen cities in a country? Obviously we would make a deal with city council that they allow this app to be free within the city"

The straightforward answers is "no, this is totally impossible", but after all I decided to ask the community here.

Maybe there is a way to set some promo codes in in app payments? I mean, the app download is free but to use this app after installation you must do some in-app purchase or fill the promo code to use the app for free. And these promo codes would be delivered to citizens in some way.

Do you have any idea how to approach such problem? Or maybe it's even pointless to look for any solution?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean in a city? - when a users moves in a city - does the functionality change within a city?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can use the promo codes**

> You can request up to 100 promo codes for every version of your app. To request promo codes for an app version, the version’s status must be Ready for Sale or Pending Developer Release.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/ProvidingPromoCodes.html

**You can send gift**

> Learn how to send iTunes Gifts in the iTunes Store, iBooks Store1, and App Store. In the iTunes Store, you can gift a dollar amount or books, audiobooks, music, movies, TV shows, or apps from your iPhone, iPod touch, iPad, Mac, or PC. Use these steps to send a gift from the iTunes Store.

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201783

Or you can use the Entreprise Distribution and make the price by your own for every client.

http://mobiledan.net/2012/03/02/5-options-for-distributing-ios-apps-to-a-limited-audience-legally/

Comment: Can I submit the same app from multiple developer accounts with just different app icon and some color difference inside the app?

Comment: Hmmm, no idea :/ But it's seems to be border line with the rules ^^

Comment: It's not an obligation to be in the App Store to sell an application ;)